# The name for injective map $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ with $f(n)\geq n$ property

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, posets

What is the name for map $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ (from natural numbers into natural numbers) with the following propeties:

1) $f$ is injective

2) $f(n)\geq n$ for every $n$?

Comment: I've heard the second called "inflationary". So I'd say "injective inflationary".

Comment: Why should every property have a name?

Comment: So, your question is really "does there already exist a name for this property"?

Comment: Todd Trimble, thanks!